# Mongo Aggregation Optimizer

Tags: mongodb, optimization, aggregation-framework

Should I let the Mongo Optimizer do the work for me, or is it worthwhile to make changes based upon the stages that are shown in the explain?

I have an identical scenario as listed in the [Mongo Optimizer Page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#project-or-unset-or-addfields-or-set-match-sequence-optimization) where I had an addFields stage followed by a match with only 1 field in the match that needed to be after the addFields stage.

The optimizer creates 1 new match stage with the fields that don't need the 'addFields' stage and puts it first.

Is it faster or better to make changes now that I see that, or does it basically execute as fast if I make no changes?

Just putting my example below for clarity:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            effectiveDate: {
                $dateFromString: {
                    dateString: '$effectiveStartOn'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $and : [
                { effectiveDate: { $lte: ISODate("2020-03-01")} },
                { first: "Baby" },
                { last: "Yoda" }
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

becomes:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $and : [
                { first: "Baby" },
                { last: "Yoda" }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            effectiveDate: {
                $dateFromString: {
                    dateString: '$effectiveStartOn'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            effectiveDate: { $lte: ISODate("2020-03-01")}
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: As docs says: `Aggregation pipeline operations have an optimization phase which attempts to reshape the pipeline for improved performance.` Since you cannot controll every your queries, MongoDb will attempt optimize each time if it can. If you define your pipeline optimized way, it's good for you.

Comment: Are you saying because it's going to attempt to optimize it anyways, there's no point? I don't see anywhere in the docs that say I SHOULD change it based upon the explain, but that I can. I'm trying to find out if it's better.